# How to set rows in a DataTable with the same column value?

Tags: c#, datatable

For instance, given the table:

| MSDS ID | Gallons | Color Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8001 | 50 | Blue1 |
| 8001 | 15 | Blue2 |
| 8001 | 30 | Blue3 |
| 8002 | 12 | Blue4 |
| 8002 | 10 | Blue5 |
| 8003 | 25 | Blue6 |

I would like to group all the rows by the MSDS ID value and set the column "Gallons" to match what's in the first row for each group.

The result should look like this:

| MSDS ID | Gallons | Color Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8001 | 50 | Blue1 |
| 8001 | 50 | Blue2 |
| 8001 | 50 | Blue3 |
| 8002 | 12 | Blue4 |
| 8002 | 12 | Blue5 |
| 8003 | 25 | Blue6 |

I'm now sure if I can do this in SQL. Here is how I'm populating it from SQL:

```
select   
  b.booth_id, b.pnt_msds msds_id, bd.colorDescription, 0.00 as Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used   
from table1  b   
join table2 bd  on bd.booth_id = b.booth_id  
where b.entry_date BETWEEN cast(@startDate as date)
  AND cast(@endDate as date) AND cast(@endDate as date) 
order by msds_id, Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used desc
```

Then I go through and populate the row Gallons programmatically as such (results from table for the Gallons column don't reflect this exactly as that's just for visualization purposes).

```
   private DataTable UpdateGallonColumns(DataTable dt)
        {

            // sets the values for the first row
            string sbooth = dt.Rows[0]["booth_id"].ToString();
            string smsds = dt.Rows[0]["msds_id"].ToString();
            
            decimal numofgallons = GetNumberOfGallons(dt.Rows[0]); 
            decimal gallonsPerMSDS = numofgallons; 
            dt.Rows[0]["Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used"] = numofgallons; 

            // foreach row in the datatable after the first row 
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1))
            {
                numofgallons = GetNumberOfGallons(row);
                if (sbooth != row["booth_id"].ToString())
                {
                    sbooth = row["booth_id"].ToString();
                    gallonsPerMSDS = numofgallons;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (smsds != row["msds_id"].ToString())
                    {
                        smsds = row["msds_id"].ToString();
                        gallonsPerMSDS = numofgallons;
                    }
                    else
                        gallonsPerMSDS += numofgallons;
                }
                row["Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used"] = gallonsPerMSDS;
           

            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: If you are populating `Gallons` programmatically, why not handle keeping the same as the first in that code? Can you change the existing `DataTable`? Why are you using `DataTable`?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, you're right. I can do it in that instance. Given table is already ordered by msds_id, how exactly do I set every row after the first row in a msds_id group to have the value from the first row?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to populate `Gallons`? You already have the result ordered by `msds_id` (though your example doesn't match your SQL) (and worthlessly by `Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used` since that is always `0.00`) so you could just remember your `msds_id` and use the previous `Gallons` when there is a match.

Comment: @NetMage I've added the method I use to populate Gallons and have reflected my table to match my Sql.

Comment: None of the columns seem to match your examples at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the source-table, use Linq to group by the ID and then modify each row:

```
DataTable resultTable = sourceTable.Copy();
var idGroups = resultTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("MSDS ID"));

foreach (var idGroup in idGroups)
{
    int gallons = idGroup.First().Field<int>("Gallons");
    foreach (DataRow row in idGroup)
        row.SetField("Gallon", gallons);
}
```

Comment: For simplicity sake, I just kept the columns to three. Realistically, my table has about 10 columns which means I would have to add all columns back to each row if I .Clone(). Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to keep the whole first DataRow of each group and repeat it group-count times?

Comment: I want to keep the first value of the "Gallons" column for each group and repeat it for each row thereafter within that group.

Answer (score 0):

So you can achieve this in sql using window functions. Here we want to use `Max` over a range. `MAX(Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used) OVER(PARTITION BY msds_id)`

Approach 1: Using CTE for original data.

```
    ;with t as (
        /* replace below with original query with join to get raw data*/
       select *
       from @t1
    )
    select msds_id, colorDescription
        ,MAX(Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used) OVER(PARTITION BY msds_id) Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used
    from t
```

Approach 2: Using view.

```
select msds_id, colorDescription
    ,MAX(Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used) OVER(PARTITION BY msds_id) Total_MSDS_Gallons_Used
from (
    /* replace below with original query with join to get raw data*/
    select *
    from @t1
)t
```